# Fitting multivariate system of ordinary differential equations (5 variables) model with R packages and Stan

Tags: c#, r

How can I do fitting of multivariate system of ordinary differential equations (5 variables) model or system with R packages with out the help of Stan interface.
for the following set of ODE's:

```r
    dS <- delta1*R - kappa1*S-beta1*S*I/N  
    dV <- kappa1*S - beta1*sigma1*V*I/N
    dE <- beta1*S*I/N + beta1*V*sigma1*I/N -gamma1*E
    dI <- gamma1*E   - I*alpha1
    dR <- alpha1*I - delta1*R
```

I have read this report and I wonder it can be applied to my system, but is there any different ways using R only?
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/fitting-multivariate-ode-models-with-brms/
Thanks

Comment: try https://github.com/parksw3/fitode ? (is the `c#` tag intentional?)

Comment: Thans a lot Dr. Bolker

Comment: HiIs there any example that I can follow similar to the link above